# convert this C++ code to MIPS?

Tags: c++, mips

I have a problem where I am supposed to write an if-else in MIPS. The problem is originally written in C++ and I have to convert it. Please help if anyone can. I specifically need to know how to set up the switch statements in mips

PROBLEM:

- if x has a value if 2, print "bbb"
- if x has a value of 3, print "ccc"
- if x has a value of 4, print "ddd"
- if x has a value other than 2, 3, or 4 print "eee"

```
result = "";

switch (x)
{  
    case 2: result = result + "bbb"; break;    
    case 3: result = result + "ccc"; break;
    case 4: result = result + "ddd"; break;
    default: result = result + "eee";
}

cout << "3.\t" << result << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a compiler and looking at the generated assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Switch in MIPS could be implemented in the following way:

```
    # register to be switched is in $s0
switch:
    addi $t0, $zero, 2
    bne $s0, $t0, case3
    # write code for case 2 here
case3:
    addi $t0, $zero, 3
    bne $s0, $t0, case4
    # write code for case 3 here
case4:
    addi $t0, $zero, 4
    bne $s0, $t0, default
    # write code for case 4 here
default:
    # write default code here
```

Also refer to the widely used [MIPS Green Card](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~wiebe/courses/CS447/MIPS_Green_Card.pdf), which I'm sure can help you with other difficulties you might face along the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
.data
msg2: asciiz "bbb"
msg3: asciiz "ccc"
msg4: asciiz "ddd"
def: asciiz "eee"
.text
main:
#get x
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t1,$v0
#x in t1
addi $t0, $zero, 2
beq $t0,$t1,printb
addi $t0, $zero, 3
beq $t0,$t1,printc
addi $t0, $zero, 4
beq $t0,$t1,printd
#if we have come this far and not branched else where means $t0 has value 
4 and didnt went to printd branch print eee
li $v0,4
la $a0,default
syscall
#end this function
li $v0,10
syscall
printb:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg2
syscall
printc:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg3
syscall

printd:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg4
syscall
```

in data msgs are defined then take an input comparing from up to down. if reached till the end means it didnot went to any branch just execute default case.